# Passbook not recognizing iBeacon

Tags: ios, passbook, ibeacon

I've been trying to get my pass to become relevant by installing it and getting near an iBeacon, but nothing I do seems to work. Does anyone have some insight into why this could be happening?

Here are a few pertinent details:

- I have no problem signing or creating the pass. I do this on the command line and email myself the pass
- I use Apple's AirLocate sample code to turn another iPhone 5s into a beacon.
- I make sure the proximity UUIDs match
- I've turned on the passbook developer debugging features in preferences but see no obvious errors in the console.

Here is the relevant part of my pass.json with my team info edited out. (you may recognize beacon tag from WWDC):

```
 {
   "formatVersion" : 1,
   "passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.com.[valid stuff here]",
   "serialNumber" : "100",
   "teamIdentifier" : "[valid team id here]",
 "beacons":[{
      "proximityUUID":"99C759FE-C660-4B95-981A-0C53E0EE6124",
      "relevantText":"Delicious food nearby"
      }],
 ...
 }
```

So I set up AirLocate with that UUID, enable the beacon, and walk around with the pass installed and get no response....

Anyone have success with this or have some questions that could help me out?

Comment: iBeacon alerts will only show on the lock screen - the device will scan for beacons when it is woken with the power button.  Also ensure that the major and minor parameters are not set as these will prevent a match.

Comment: Have you tried using the CoreLocation CLBeaconRegion to see if you can trigger the detection of an iBeacon outside of Passbook?

Comment: Does AirLocate on the 2nd iOS device (the one with passbook) see the iBeacon?

Comment: Take in account that the type of the pass does matter for relevant notifications. For iBeacons the rules are basically the same as they are for locations. Use `storeCard` to be 100 per-cent sure you are not falling within other relevant rules.

Comment: JSON looks ok for me and I used something identical with a generic type and it worked. Main issue was that I really had to move around to trigger the event (staying at my desk and switching the beacon on and off wasn't enough)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not specifying major/minor in your pass definition, you need to make sure that your iBeacon is set the same way. I would also suggest to confirm that your pass.json is correct, One way to confirm would be to write a simple app using CoreLocations and see if you can communicate with your beacon that way, alternatively, you can generate your pass using one of the online tools ( http://essentialtechnologies.ca ) just to confirm that your syntax is not causing your problem

Comment: "Since you are not specifying major/minor in your pass definition, you need to make sure that your iBeacon is set the same way." This is incorrect. A beacon will always transmit UUID, major and minor. It is perfectly legitimate to listen just for UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the following things when testing iBeacons in Passbook passes:

- Always us a **major** and a **minor** definition of the Bluetooth beacon you are trying to target (default is both 1). The major attribute is used for a group of beacons, the minor field can point to a specific beacon.
- Make sure you have enabled **location services** (Settings -> Privacy -> Location services) and **notifications** (Settings -> Notification Center) for Passbook.
- Notifications show up in a different way than regular push notifications. When you're close to a beacon the notification shows up in an unobtrusive way on your lock screen.
- There are a number of apps that you can use to simulate iBeacons, for example MacBeacon for OSX (http://www.radiusnetworks.com/macbeacon-app.html) or Locate for iOS (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8)
- There is a bug in iOS 7.0.3 (fixed in iOS 7.1) that crashses iOS when opening a notification (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5517831?tstart=0)

Comment: "Always us a major and a minor definition of the Bluetooth beacon you are trying to target." This is not required. It is perfectly legitimate to listen just for UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Bluetooth is on and Location services is enabled for your app. Also, if you have any Android device around, you can use [iBeacon Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate) to make sure your devices are emitting.

I can confirm (as the documentation says) that you don't need `minor` nor `major` defined.

Here's a pass JSON I use and works with an iBeacon we have here:

```
{
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.com.[...]",
  "serialNumber" : "E5982H-I2",
  "teamIdentifier" : "[...]",
  "webServiceURL" : "https://example.com/passes/",
  "authenticationToken" : "vxwxd7J8AlNNFPS8k0a0FfUFtq0ewzFdc",
  "barcode" : {
    "message" : "123456789",
    "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
    "messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1"
  },
  "beacons": [
    {
      "proximityUUID": "[...]",
      "relevantText": "You are here!"
    }
  ],
  "organizationName" : "Paw Planet",
  "description" : "Coupon for a free lollipop at Example Candy Store",
  "logoText" : "Example Candy Store",
  "foregroundColor" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
  "backgroundColor" : "rgb(206, 140, 53)",
  "coupon" : {
    "primaryFields" : [
        {
            "key": "offer",
            "value": "Free lollipop",
            "label": "On July 29"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the major and minor per below where aaaaa is the major value and bbbbb is the minor from your beacon.

```
"beacons": [
    {
      "proximityUUID": "[...]",
      "relevantText": "You are here!"
      "major":aaaaa
      "minor":bbbbb
    } 
  ],
```

Comment: This is not required. It is perfectly legitimate to listen just for UUID.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing helps you try to **reboot** your device AND/OR **turn off/on Bluetooth**.
Some guys say iOS can stop ranging beacons unexpectedly.
http://beekn.net/2014/05/beacon-bug-apple-loses-ibeacon-ranging-drives-developers-mad/

In my case Passbook notified me after 10 minutes I was near iBeacon %)

Happy coding!